# ¿Por qué me sale este error en php?

Tags: php, mysql, netbeans, apache

estoy haciendo un proyecto y ya llevo la mayor parte de el. pero ahora me sale el siguiente error. que la verdad he investigado mucho y no encuentro el porque del mismo.

Error fatal : ArgumentCountError no capturado: filter_input() espera al menos 2 argumentos, 1 dado en C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject3prueba\index.php:21 Rastreo de pila: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject3prueba\index.php( 21): filter_input(0) #1 {main} lanzado en C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject3prueba\index.php en la línea 21

adjunto mi codigo abajo: [image: en el error dice que es la linea 21, pero no se que hacer para resolverlo, seria de gran ayuda una respuesta :)]

Comment: En la linea 21 del index.php no tienes nada, es una linea en blanco. ¿Seguro que el error coincide con el código que nos estás mostrando?  Comprueba si usas el filter_input **antes** de la linea 21 y cuantos parámetros tiene, pues tiene pinta de que el error está por encima de esa linea.

Comment: si lo acabo de notar , ahora me aparece el error en la linea 26 , en el filter_input :(

Comment: Pulsa en [edit]  y coloca el código como texto, basta con copiar/pegar. Las capturas de pantalla para código dificultan analizar el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Sebastian, haces un `filter_input(INPUT_REQUEST,'enviar')`, donde pones como primer parámetro **`INPUT_REQUEST`**, que no es ninguna de las válidas para esa función: **`INPUT_GET, INPUT_POST, INPUT_COOKIE, INPUT_SERVER o INPUT_ENV`**

Echa un vistazo a [la documentación de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.filter-input.php) donde te explica el uso de la función.